# How to verify the app development language of a published IOS/Android app?

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode

Is there a way to figure out the language an app has been developed in (eg Swift, react,...) by looking at some packaged installed version on either operating system?
For example how to know if Duolingo has been written in Swift or other?

Comment: Xcode isn't a language, its an IDE.  You can write multiple languages using it.  You can tell react native by looking and checking if the react native library is in the decompiled apk  on an android device.  But please note that an app doesn't have to use 1 language.  It can use multiple.  Its not uncommon for large apps to have a small part written in react native as a test, or if it has a website as well for parts to just open the website if they haven't written it natively yet (password reset is a common part to do this).

Answer (score 2):

Github displays the language of all public repositories. So if you look at open-source libraries or apps. For example, this well-known library, Kingfisher as below.

[image]

Comment: Good idea to look at the github repos?